# PHP - Get the value of an unknown array key

Tags: php, json

Based on this result from an API

```
"name": {
    "common": "Italy",
    "official": "Italian Republic",
    "nativeName": {
        "ita": {
            "official": "Repubblica italiana",
            "common": "Italia"
        }
    }
},
```

Let's suppose i always want the "common" name but, depending on the country the "key" will vary (now it's "ita" but it could be anything)

What is the cleanest way to always get the "common" value independently of the key name above? (so a dynamic function that always get the common value)

Answer (score 1):

With fixed structures you can do that:

```
$arr = json_decode('{"name": {
    "common": "Italy",
    "official": "Italian Republic",
    "nativeName": {
        "ita": {
            "official": "Repubblica italiana",
            "common": "Italia"
        }
    }
}}',true);

$country = key($arr['name']['nativeName']);  //ita
$common = $arr['name']['nativeName'][$country]['common'];  //Italia

echo '$country = '.$country.', $common = '.$common;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/W4sqI

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over that part of the data structure like this to get both the key and the value of `common`

```
$json = '{
    "name": {
    "common": "Italy",
    "official": "Italian Republic",
    "nativeName": {
        "ita": {
            "official": "Repubblica italiana",
            "common": "Italia"
        }
    }
}
}';


foreach (json_decode($json)->name->nativeName as $key => $native){
    echo "Key = $key, common = {$native->common}";
}
```

RESULT

```
Key = ita, common = Italia
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_mangled_object_vars()` with `key()` if you have just one `nativeName` like:

```
$a = json_decode('{"name": {
    "common": "Italy",
    "official": "Italian Republic",
    "nativeName": {
        "ita": {
            "official": "Repubblica italiana",
            "common": "Italia"
        }
    }
}}');
print_r(key(get_mangled_object_vars($a->name->nativeName))); // ita
```

Reference:

- [get_mangled_object_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-mangled-object-vars.php)
- [key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key)

---

Or you can use `ArrayObject` combine with `getIterator()` and `key()` like:

```
$a = json_decode('{"name": {
        "common": "Italy",
        "official": "Italian Republic",
        "nativeName": {
            "ita": {
                "official": "Repubblica italiana",
                "common": "Italia"
            }
        }
}}');
$arrayobject = new ArrayObject($a->name->nativeName);
$iterator = $arrayobject->getIterator();
echo $iterator->key(); //ita
```

Reference:

- [ArrayObject](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.construct)
- [getIterator()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.getiterator)
- [key()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayiterator.key)